# Method Delete with Express, Axios and React not work

Tags: javascript, express, axios

i have a problem, i trying do the method delete with `Express, Axios and React`but they are giving error e not working...

My code with `AXIOS.JS with REACT`:

```js
remove = (name, id) => {
  axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people/' + id).
  then((response => id.splice(name, 1)))
}
```

My `EXPRESS.JS`:

```js
app.delete('/people', function (req, res) {
  res.send('DELETE request to homepage');
});
```

And the errors:

> OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:9000/people/0 404 (Not Found)
>
> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:9000/people/0: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

Someone help me please?

Comment: have you checked your server log? sometimes, if server crashes while serving the request (due to any error), it turns out to same kind of problem.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'd be interested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have to enable CORS in Express, take a look at this answer: [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem of CORS was fixed :))) but others problems continue.. :(((

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to send `ID` as request parameter to your backed.

You'll have to

Change `axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people/' + id).`

to `axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people/:'  id)`.

And

```
app.delete('/people', function (req, res) {
```

To

```
 app.delete('/people/id', function (req, res) {
```

You also need to enable `CORS` on your server side

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers but the problem continue.. :(

Comment: Sorry missed that part. Try now

Comment: The part of the CORS was solved, thank you very much. But the problem still continues... :(

Comment: axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people/:'  id)   this syntax wrong.